# Creating a scope-independent fadein/fadeout directive in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

To set the stage - this is not happening within a single scope, where I can bind a simple attribute. The element I want to fade in/out does not sit inside a controller, it sits inside the ng-app (rootScope). Further, the button that's clicked is in a child scope about 3 children deep from root.

Here is how I'm currently solving this:

HTML (sitting in root scope):

```
<ul class="nav-secondary actions" 
  darthFader fadeDuration="200" 
  fadeEvent="darthFader:secondaryNav">
```

Where darthFader is my directive.

Directive:

directive('darthFader',

```
function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function($scope, element, attrs) {
                $scope.$on(attrs.fadeevent, function(event,options) {
                    $(element)["fade" + options.fade || "In"](attrs.fadeduration || 200);
                });
            }
        }

})
```

So here I'm creating an event handler, specific to a given element, that is calling fadeIn or fadeOut, depending on an option being passed through the event bus (or defaulting to fadeIn/200ms).

I am then broadcasting an event from $rootScope to trigger this event:

```
$rootScope.$broadcast('darthFader:secondaryNav', { fade: "Out"});
```

While this works, I'm not crazy about creating an event listener for every instance of this directive (while I don't anticipate having too many darthFader's on a screen, it's more for the pattern I would establish). I'm also not crazy about coupling my attribute in my view with an event handler in both my controller & directive, but I don't currently have a controller wrapping the secondary-nav, so I'd have to bind the secondaryNav to $rootScope, which I don't love either. So my questions:

1. Is there a way to do this without creating an event handler every time I instantiate my directive? (maybe a service to store a stateful list of elements?)
2. How should I decouple my view, controller & directive?
3. Any other obvious questions I'm missing?

Cheers!

Comment: have you finish it? would you like to share it with me? thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You mention in your question

> The element I want to fade in/out does not sit inside a controller, it sits inside the ng-app (rootScope).

I believe if I were to write this same functionality, I would put the element in its own controller--controllers are responsible for managing the intersection of the view and the model, which is exactly what you're trying to do.

```javascript
myApp.controller('NavController', function($scope) {
  $scope.fadedIn = false;
});
```

```html
<ul ng-controller="NavController"
  class="nav-secondary actions" 
  darthFader fadeDuration="200" 
  fadeShown="fadedIn">
```

```javascript
myApp.directive('darthFader', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function($scope, element, attrs) {
      var duration = attrs.fadeDuration || 200;
      $scope.$watch(attrs.fadeShown, function(value) {
        if (value)
          $(element).fadeIn(duration);
        else
          $(element).fadeOut(duration);
      });
     }
   };
});
```

If you're worried about sharing the fade in/out state between multiple controllers, you should create a service to share this state. (You could also use `$rootScope` and event handlers, but I generally find shared services easier to debug and test.)

```javascript
myApp.value('NavigationState', {
  shown: false
});

myApp.controller('NavController', function($scope, NavigationState) {
  $scope.nav = NavigationState;
});

myApp.controller('OtherController', function($scope, NavigationState) {
  $scope.showNav = function() {
    NavigationState.shown = true;
  };

  $scope.hideNav = function() {
    NavigationState.shown = false;
  };
});
```

```html
<ul ng-controller="NavController"
  class="nav-secondary actions" 
  darthFader fadeDuration="200" 
  fadeShown="nav.shown">

<!-- ..... -->

<div ng-controller="OtherController">
  <button ng-click="showNav()">Show Nav</button>
  <button ng-click="hideNav()">Hide Nav</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed sample code. I don't think this resolves the issue of .. how do I update $scope.fadedIn in the parent scope from a nested child scope? Do I $emit up to it? I don't want shared scope in my directive (I want these events to be independent of one another - read: fadeIn/fadeOut elements independent of one another)... if I $emit, how do I make sure I'm only capturing the event to hide/show this particular element?

Comment: You would update the "parent" scope by getting a reference to `NavigationState`, either by accessing `nav` directly on the scope, or passing it into a directive via an attribute (e.g. with an isolate scope) or shared service (depending on how generic they are).

Comment: So I wasn't planning to go the service route because I don't need a singleton, I need an instance of the fadedIn variable per view. I suppose I could still create a service that exposes a property per view (e.g. secondaryNavFadedIn, someOtherElementFadedIn, etc) then bind my parent $`scope.fadedIn = MyService.secondaryNavFadedIn`. From my child controller, inject the service & set the property on the service, which will then be picked up by the $watcher in my directive. That what you're suggesting?

Comment: Something along those lines; it's hard to say exactly without more information about your app. Your service can also be a function that looks up an object based on some key name, or you can even have multiple services.

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom service, inject it in the controller. Call a method on that service that will do the fade-in/fade-out etc. Pass a parameter to convey additional information.

Comment: Misko said in his best practices talk that you shouldn't do DOM manipulation in a service. That's why I haven't done what I proposed in question 1. Thoughts?

Comment: I understand. But you don't have a whole lot of options. Also we are not adding/removing dom elements. We are just fading the element. Nothing major.